# Change the third comma with : regex

Tags: regex

I want to change the third comma in this string using regex in notepad ++

```
145, 45, 67, 688
```

With a ":"
Like this :

```
145, 45, 67: 688
```

I tried this

```
(?:,)(,)*
```

I think I am missing something

Comment: Is the third comma also always the last comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the third comma is always the last, you can check for the end of the string/line with `$`:

```
,(?=[^,]*$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/c0XANJ/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression in the dialog window:

Find what: `^(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),`

Replace with: `\1:`

The first `^` matches at the start of the line. The expression `([^,]*,){2}` matches everything up to a comma two times. The expression `[^,]*` then matches everything up to, but excluding, the third comma. The first so called capture group is referred to by `\1`. In this case it refers to what's inside the outermost parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
^((\d+, ){2})(\d+),(.*)
```

Then the replacement is `\1\3:\4`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TMPMGd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could match the digits followed by optional spaces and a comma, then use `\K` to clear the match buffer, then match the third comma and replace with `:`

```
^(?:\d+,\h*){2}\d+\h*\K,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lFqcLB/1)

Or you can match the 3rd comma and replace it with `:`

```
^(?:[^\r\n,]*,){2}[^\r\n,]*\K,
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^\r\n,]*,){2}` Repeat 2 times matching any char except `,` followed by a comma
- `[^\r\n,]*`Optionally match any char except `,` or a newline
- `\K,` Clear the match buffer and match the `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JlVIVa/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the third comma is always last comma? Then using
`.*` as greedy will perform the job,  so the shortest code will be.
Find: `^(.*),`
Replace it with: `$1:`